# Error while building Android project . "AAPT process not ready to receive commands"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit os**. And I update my Android Studio 2.2.2 to 2.3.3, after upgrading I can't build my projects. When I try to build my projects Android Studio always shows error like

```
 Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
 > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
```

this is my **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "akhil.com.d4donline"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a well knew bug in Linux, just downgrade the build version to 23:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

. . .

defaultConfig {
    . . .

    targetSdkVersion 23

    . . .
```

And you probably also have to change the **gradle version to 2.2**

Comment: Why do Google's programs still fail to fix it?